# how to fix the displayed table in php

Tags: php, css, foreach, html-table

I have a code that read from text files and allow the user to make a search then the system display the result in a table that contains the file name and the line number.

what I need is to delete the columns that are empty.

I will appreciate any help.

screenshot:
[image: displayed result]

Where is the error in the table?

Code of table and Style:

```
   //display the table
    echo '<table class = "minimalistBlack" border=2>';

    $filenameHtml    = '<tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml    = '<tr>';
    foreach ($result as $item){
     $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
     $lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
     //$filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";
     $new_filename = str_replace('.txt', '.pdf',$filename);
     $filenameHtml .= "<th><a href ='".$new_filename."'target='_blank'>$filename</a></th>";
     $lineNumberHtml .= "<td>$lines</td>";
    }
    $filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml  .= '</tr>';

    echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
    echo '</table>';
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ar-sa">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style>
          #form {
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        background: linear-gradient(bottom, #CCCCCC, #EEEEEE 175px);
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: absolute;


        font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-style: italic;
        line-height: 24px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #09C;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        border: inset 1px solid #333;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }


      table.minimalistBlack {
  border: 3px solid #80E0FF;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.minimalistBlack td, table.minimalistBlack th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 4px;
}
table.minimalistBlack tbody td {
  font-size: 12px;
}
table.minimalistBlack thead {
  background: #CFCFCF;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #dbdbdb 0%, #d3d3d3 66%, #CFCFCF 100%);
  border-bottom: 3px solid #000000;
}
table.minimalistBlack thead th {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: left;
}
table.minimalistBlack tfoot {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000000;
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
}
table.minimalistBlack tfoot td {
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the column if it contains no value, like this :

```
<?php

echo '<table class = "minimalistBlack" border=2>';

$filenameHtml    = '<tr>';
$lineNumberHtml    = '<tr>';
foreach ($result as $item){
$filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
$lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
//$filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";
$new_filename = str_replace('.txt', '.pdf',$filename);
$filenameHtml .= !empty($filename) ? "<th><a href ='".$new_filename."'target='_blank'>$filename</a></th>" : ''; // added !empty()
$lineNumberHtml .= !empty($lines) ? "<td>$lines</td>" : ''; // added !empty()
}
$filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';
$lineNumberHtml  .= '</tr>';

echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a checker if the filename or lines has value. If none, then dont display it. see code below:

```html
echo '<table class = "minimalistBlack" border=2>';

    $filenameHtml    = '<tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml    = '<tr>';
    foreach ($result as $item){
     $filename = isset($item['filename']) ? $item['filename'] : '';
     $lines = isset($item['lines']) ? implode(',',$item['lines']) : '';
     //$filenameHtml .= "<th>$filename</th>";
     $new_filename = str_replace('.txt', '.pdf',$filename);

     if(strlen($filename)>0 || strlen($lines)>0){ // Check if filename OR lines has value
      $filenameHtml .= "<th><a href ='".$new_filename."'target='_blank'>$filename</a></th>";
      $lineNumberHtml .= "<td>$lines</td>";
   }
    }
    $filenameHtml    .= '</tr>';
    $lineNumberHtml  .= '</tr>';

    echo $filenameHtml.$lineNumberHtml;
    echo '</table>';
```